# how to organize the code when multi varibales get data form multi sources?

Tags: design-patterns

I have an API that return a struct which contains variables: a, b and c.
To get the value of a,b,c, I have to get original data from multi services,e.g. , S1,S2.
S1 returns a1,b1,and S2 returns b2,c2
Now I have to calculate the value of a using a1 and c using c2 and b using b1 and b2.
So in this case, how to organize the code?
e.g.:

```
ReqS1();    // here to calculate a and store b1
ReqS2();    // here to calculate b and c
```

or

```
ReqS1();  // here to store a1 and b1
ReqS2();  // here to store b2 and c2
CalculateA();  // here to calculate a
CalculateB();  // here to calculate b
CalculateC();  // here to calculate c
```

or any other better ways?

Answer (score 2):

Your design decision would depend on if you have control over the services, if so change s1 for example to return a1 & c2, and s2 to return b1& b2 then do the follwing:

```
ReqS1();  // here to store a1 and b1
CalculateA();  // here to calculate a
CalculateC();  // here to calculate c
ReqS2();  // here to store b2 and c2
CalculateB();  // here to calculate b
```

otherwise you should go with the second approach, since the calculation of a for example would be useless if for example `ReqS2()` failed to retrieve b2 and c2, so you will not return the new struct that holds a,b and c.